# Error: Calendar cannot be resolved in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, date, get

I tried to get date in JSP like what I searched before, but it didn't work. Here is my code.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.text.*;" errorPage="" %>
    <%!
        DateFormat tipe = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    %>
    <% 
        out.print(tipe.format(cal.getTime()));
    %>
```

Why it said "Calendar cannot be resolved"? Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Calendar` is in a `java.util` package. You are missing import.

Answer (score 3):

Updated code should look like:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.util.*, java.text.*;" errorPage="" %>
    <%!
        DateFormat tipe = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    %>
    <% 
        out.print(tipe.format(cal.getTime()));
    %>
```

Answer (score 2):

import Calendar class like below

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>
```